# Trouble using for-each loop when creating users in TF

Tags: loops, terraform

I'd like to automate a task using TF. The idea is simple:

From a .csv file, get the users, groups, and passwords to be created in AWS as IAM users.

I've managed to create users and adding them to groups when using the same loop for `aws_iam_user` and `aws_iam_user_group_membership`.

However, when I try to set their passwords, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

on main.tf line 32, in resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass":
32:   user     = each.value.usuarios #PROBLEM HERE! IT GENERATES A TUPLE BUT I ONLY WANT 1 USER PER LOOP!!
|----------------
| each.value is a tuple with 4 elements

This value does not have any attributes.
```

The code is:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-2"
}


# Lê csv e transforma em map para ser consumido
locals {
  csv_data = file("${path.module}/usuarios2.csv")
  users = csvdecode(local.csv_data)
}

# Cria os usuários, atribui senhas e os adiciona em seus respectivos grupos
resource "aws_iam_user" "usuarios" {
  for_each = { for usuario in local.users : usuario.usuarios => usuario }
  name = each.value.usuarios
}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass" {
  for_each = { for newPass in local.users : newPass.senha => newPass... }
  user     = each.value.usuarios #PROBLEM HERE! IT GENERATES A TUPLE BUT I ONLY WANT 1 USER PER LOOP!!
  pgp_key  = "keybase:$user" 

#   output "password" {
#     value = aws_iam_user_login_profile.example.encrypted_password
#   }
}


resource "aws_iam_user_group_membership" "add-group" {
  for_each = { for newGroup in local.users : newGroup.grupo => newGroup }

  user = each.value.usuarios
  groups = [
    each.value.grupo,
  ]

}
```

I'm aware of what the problem is, but I not being able to fix it.

Could anyone give me a hand here?

Cheers!

Mock csv: [testemybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/usuarios2.csv](https://testemybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/usuarios2.csv)

EDIT:

If I use a different loop:

```
# Atribui senhas aos users
resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass" {
  for_each = aws_iam_user.usuarios
  user     = each.value.name
  pgp_key  = "keybase:${each.value.name}"
}
```

Now it returns:

```
  # aws_iam_user_login_profile.add-pass["amelia.penteado"] will be created
  + resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass" {
      + encrypted_password      = (known after apply)
      + id                      = (known after apply)
      + key_fingerprint         = (known after apply)
      + password_length         = 20
      + password_reset_required = true
      + pgp_key                 = "keybase:amelia.penteado"
      + user                    = "amelia.penteado"
    }

Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_iam_user_login_profile.add-pass["amelia.penteado"]: Creating...
aws_iam_user_login_profile.add-pass["alda.lage"]: Creating...
aws_iam_user_login_profile.add-pass["aguinaldo.balsemao"]: Creating...
aws_iam_user_login_profile.add-pass["adolfo.carlos"]: Creating...

Error: error retrieving GPG Key during IAM User Login Profile (aguinaldo.balsemao) creation: Error retrieving Public Key for keybase:aguinaldo.balsemao: got non-OK response: "INPUT_ERROR"

  on main.tf line 101, in resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass":
 101: resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass" {
```

**UPDATE:**

I solved the issue using another approach:

I defined a null_resource in Terraform

```
resource "null_resource" "Add-users-pass" {

 provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = "/bin/bash chmod +x ./cria-users.sh || ./cria-users.sh"
  }
}
```

And used it to run a bash script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=./usuarios2.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
echo "While "
while read -r usuario grupo senha || [ -n "$usuario" ]
do
    if [ "$usuario" != "usuarios" ]; then
        aws iam create-user --user-name $usuario
        aws iam create-login-profile --password-reset-required --user-name $usuario --password $senha
        aws iam add-user-to-group --group-name $grupo --user-name $usuario
    fi
done < "$INPUT"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: What is `local.users`?

Comment: Can you share the structure of the cvs file?

Comment: try with `for_each = { for newPass in local.users : newPass.senha => newPass }` without `...` after `newPass`

Comment: @Marcin, local.users is part of csvdecode. It tells Terraform to use the local_id value to track each instance it creates.

Comment: @SimoneRipamonti, that was the first approach, but then it returns:

`Error: Duplicate object key

  on main.tf line 108, in resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "add-pass":
 108:   for_each = { for newPass in local.users : newPass.senha => newPass }
    |----------------
    | newPass.senha is "MeMuda123456"

Two different items produced the key "MeMuda123456" in this 'for' expression.
If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression
to enable grouping by key.`

Comment: @PeterArboleda, sure, link is: testemybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/usuarios2.csv or  `usuarios,grupo,senha adolfo.carlos,DBA,MeMuda123456 aguinaldo.balsemao,RedesAdmin,MeMuda123456 alda.lage,CloudAdmin,MeMuda123456 amelia.penteado,LinuxAdmin,MeMuda123456`

Comment: I mean the actual example values in the csvdecode.

Comment: @xJuggl3r Use `newPass.usuarios => newPass`. The key you choose must be unique and I assume usernames are unique in your csv

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I solved the issue using another approach:

I defined a null_resource in Terraform

```
resource "null_resource" "Add-users-pass" {

 provisioner "local-exec" {

    command = "/bin/bash chmod +x ./cria-users.sh || ./cria-users.sh"
  }
}
```

And used it to run a bash script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=./usuarios2.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
echo "While "
while read -r usuario grupo senha || [ -n "$usuario" ]
do
    if [ "$usuario" != "usuarios" ]; then
        aws iam create-user --user-name $usuario
        aws iam create-login-profile --password-reset-required --user-name $usuario --password $senha
        aws iam add-user-to-group --group-name $grupo --user-name $usuario
    fi
done < "$INPUT"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: Some points to consider. Overall, the problem is still not solved.
I mean, it's ok to use null_resource in this specific case, considering that this action will once run one. But in other cases, adding the users by using null_resource to run a bash script will affect `terraform destroy` and users will be not removed from their groups.